# django socketio - SocketIOHandler error

Tags: python, django, sockets, socket.io, django-socketio

i can't use [django-socketio](https://github.com/stephenmcd/django-socketio), i get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'SocketIOHandler' object has no attribute 'response_headers_list'
```

Terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Volumes/DATA/Projekti/virtualenv/caffetouch/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/greenlet.py", line 327, in run
    result = self._run(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/Volumes/DATA/Projekti/virtualenv/caffetouch/lib/python2.7/site-packages/socketio/server.py", line 49, in handle
    handler.handle()
  File "/Volumes/DATA/Projekti/virtualenv/caffetouch/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/pywsgi.py", line 184, in handle
    result = self.handle_one_request()
  File "/Volumes/DATA/Projekti/virtualenv/caffetouch/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/pywsgi.py", line 321, in handle_one_request
    self.handle_one_response()
  File "/Volumes/DATA/Projekti/virtualenv/caffetouch/lib/python2.7/site-packages/socketio/handler.py", line 58, in handle_one_response
    self.handle_one_response(call_wsgi_app=False)
TypeError: handle_one_response() got an unexpected keyword argument 'call_wsgi_app'
<Greenlet at 0x10247ac30: <bound method SocketIOServer.handle of <SocketIOServer at 0x1028ce8d0 fileno=5 address=127.0.0.1:8000>>(<socket at 0x102976210 fileno=[Errno 9] Bad file d, ('127.0.0.1', 51457))> failed with TypeError

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Volumes/DATA/Projekti/virtualenv/caffetouch/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/greenlet.py", line 327, in run
    result = self._run(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/Volumes/DATA/Projekti/virtualenv/caffetouch/lib/python2.7/site-packages/socketio/server.py", line 49, in handle
    handler.handle()
  File "/Volumes/DATA/Projekti/virtualenv/caffetouch/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/pywsgi.py", line 184, in handle
    result = self.handle_one_request()
  File "/Volumes/DATA/Projekti/virtualenv/caffetouch/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/pywsgi.py", line 321, in handle_one_request
    self.handle_one_response()
  File "/Volumes/DATA/Projekti/virtualenv/caffetouch/lib/python2.7/site-packages/socketio/handler.py", line 68, in handle_one_response
    jobs = self.transport.connect(session, request_method)
  File "/Volumes/DATA/Projekti/virtualenv/caffetouch/lib/python2.7/site-packages/socketio/transports.py", line 92, in connect
    self.write_packed(session_id)
  File "/Volumes/DATA/Projekti/virtualenv/caffetouch/lib/python2.7/site-packages/socketio/transports.py", line 19, in write_packed
    self.write(data)
  File "/Volumes/DATA/Projekti/virtualenv/caffetouch/lib/python2.7/site-packages/socketio/transports.py", line 22, in write
    if 'Content-Length' not in self.handler.response_headers_list:
AttributeError: 'SocketIOHandler' object has no attribute 'response_headers_list'
<Greenlet at 0x10247ac30: <bound method SocketIOServer.handle of <SocketIOServer at 0x1028ce8d0 fileno=5 address=127.0.0.1:8000>>(<socket at 0x102976210 fileno=[Errno 9] Bad file d, ('127.0.0.1', 51460))> failed with AttributeError
```

I think this is showing becouse it isn't supported with new django, or something like this.

Any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope it won't be too late. It's actually a compatibility issue. You need to uninstall some newer packages. See [here](https://github.com/stephenmcd/django-socketio/issues/63).

Here is part of my configuration. It works.

```
$ pip list
Django (1.6.7)
django-socketio (0.3.8)
gevent (0.13.6)
gevent-socketio (0.2.1)
gevent-websocket (0.2.3)
greenlet (0.4.5)
pip (1.5.6)
setuptools (6.0.2)
sphinx-me (0.3)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using django 1.8 or above then you need to uninstall new version and install the previous version using the given command:

```
pip install django-socketio==0.3.9
pip uninstall gevent-socketio gevent
pip install gevent-socketio==0.2.1 gevent==0.13.6
```

For more details, see the following thread: https://github.com/stephenmcd/django-socketio/issues/63